# NDEBUG must not be defined when _DEBUG is defined

Tags: visual-c++

Im getting an error while creating an .exe project. The error is :
Compiling...

```
1>  KsmXmlXalan.cpp
1>c:\newdir\xalan-c-r786300\inc\xalanc\include\vcppdefinitions.hpp(73): fatal error C1189: #error :  NDEBUG must not be defined when _DEBUG is defined.
1>  KsmXmlJB.cpp
1>  KsmXml.cpp
1>c:\newdir\xalan-c-r786300\inc\xalanc\include\vcppdefinitions.hpp(73): fatal error C1189: #error :  NDEBUG must not be defined when _DEBUG is defined.
1>  KsmXalan.cpp
1>c:\newdir\xalan-c-r786300\inc\xalanc\include\vcppdefinitions.hpp(73): fatal error C1189: #error :  NDEBUG must not be defined when _DEBUG is defined.
```

Even though i have not defined _DEBUG (in project->properties->C/C++->Preprocessors->preprocessor Definations) but still getting the same error.

Can any one guide me why it giving this error?

Advance Thanks,
Regards,
Nagesh

Answer (score 2):

`_DEBUG` is always predefined by the preprocessor when you build against the “Debug” run-time libraries. See [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) and [Debug Routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1666sb98.aspx) in the MSDN library for more information.

`NDEBUG` is traditionally defined in a “Release” build (to remove `assert()` calls, among other things), but it’s not predefined by the preprocessor.

So it looks like you’re compiling against the debug libraries but have also got `NDEBUG` defined somewhere.  Having both defined at the same time is probably asking for trouble; the *vcppdefinitions.hpp* header file is checking for that and throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

`_DEBUG` is defined somewhere along the way.

You can do a simple thing though:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#endif

#include "vcppdefinitions.hpp"

//....

#ifdef DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#undef DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#define _DEBUG
#endif
```

The error generally happens when mixing debug with non-debug libraries.